# Is there a simple way to shift these rectangles in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Consider the following figure.

[image]

This isn't quite what I want. I'd like the rectangles to join "cleanly" (making a `+` sign).

This figure was produced with the following code.

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[
  , anchor=south west
  , draw
  , ultra thick
  ] {hello};

  \node[
  , anchor=north east
  , draw
  , ultra thick
  ] {world};


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I could do something like find the width of the stroke of the rectangles and then use `xshift` and `yshift` to align them appropriately, but this is annoying as I'd have to manually make changes if I ever changed the stroke. Is there a better way?

For clarity, I want the figure to look like this:

[image]

Comment: Try `\begin{tikzpicture}[outer sep=0pt]`.

Comment: Ahh yes. Thank you! (feel free to post as an answer and I'll accept)

Comment: Adding `shift={(\pgflinewidth,\pgflinewidth)}` to *world* node options is another solution

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick  another way with `pgflinewidth` is added below in addition to the excellent answers above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One more way may interest

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0pt]
  \node[draw, ultra thick,](a) {hello} node[draw, ultra thick ](b) [above right=-1.5\pgflinewidth of a] {world};


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```